# Robot Framework - Ride: Post Request unable to get response body

Tags: robotframework

I Wrote this test where i post a contract in a backoffice system. I made a keyword with a forloop which picks up xmls from a systemfolder.

In order to make the test pass, i want to check the values in de response. When I use RF/Ride to perform this test it is not possible to get the responsebody, if i conduct the same test in Postman/SoapUI i can see the responsebody

When i ask for the response.headers i get the expected data

The test in Ride:

```
*** Test Cases *** XML
    [Template]    Template post contract BO
    apitest1.xml
*** Keywords *** Template post contract BO
    [Arguments]    @{bestandlijst}
    : FOR    ${bestand}    IN    @{bestandlijst}
    \    &{headers}=    Create dictionary    Content-type=application/xml
    \    ${bestandophalen}=    Get Binary File    ${bestand}
    \    Create Session    Backoffice    https://url        
    \    ${response}=    Post Request    Backoffice    /isCOBOL(API_V1_ARCONTRACT)    headers=&{headers}    data=${bestandophalen}
    \    log    ${response.headers} -> this works
    \    log    ${response.body} -> this doesn't work
```

Response in Postman:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Retourbericht xmlns="http://url/schemas/things">
    <Statuscode>OK</Statuscode>
    <Statusmelding>Contract opgeslagen in de backoffice.</Statusmelding>
    <TransactionResponse>Onbekend.</TransactionResponse>
</Retourbericht>
```

Error given in ride:

```
FAIL : Resolving variable '${response.body}' failed: AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'body'
```

1. Does my test have an error, which results in this error?
2. Has anyone expirienced the same problem and what was your solution?

Comment: What library are you using? Is it documented to return an object with the `body` attribute? The standard python requests library doesn't return an object with a `body` attribute.

Comment: We use the requestslibrary. Well that is a good question, my collegue uses it as well and with him it works. Well his api's give json responses and my xml. I checked the library and couldn't find anything about returning an object though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using [RequestsLibrary](http://bulkan.github.io/robotframework-requests/), it is built on top of the python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library. This library returns a response object, but that object does not have a `body` attribute. That is why you get the AttributeError.

You can use `${response.json()}` if you want the structured data, or `${response.text}` if you want the raw text of the response as a string.